# Why isn't our object deleting? Node, Mongo, html

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, rest, backend

Our objects are built by the users passing info through a form. 
We can successfully create and post objects just fine, but we can not delete them.

I've tried many different routes/calls for this but none of them have been successful.

Here is our HTML button to trigger the delete call in Node:

```
   <form  id='deleteMe' name='deleteMe' method='delete' action=''deleteMe'> 
    <input name='_method' value='delete'>
   <button type='submit'> delete </button></form>
```

here is the express route for the deletion itself.

```
router.post('/deleteMe', function (req, res, next) {
    const _id = req.body.id

    mongoose.connect(URL, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, id)
        db.collection('spots').deleteOne({ "_id": objectId(_id) }, function (err, result) {
            console.log('op')
            assert.equal(null, err);
            db.close();
        })
    });
})
```

Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide any error occurring, if there is any?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error- the route is not even being called b/c i can not get the button to trigger it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `delete` method in you form, which is correct and post method on you express server, try using `router.delete` instead of `router.post`, like this,

```
router.delete('/deleteMe', function (req, res, next) {
    const _id = req.body.id

    mongoose.connect(URL, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, id)
        db.collection('spots').deleteOne({ "_id": objectId(_id) }, function (err, result) {
            console.log('op')
            assert.equal(null, err);
            db.close();
        })
    });
})
```

Also on your form you have a syntax error on action attribute it should be `action='deleteMe'`

Comment: FYI: If you are repeating this connection to the database, connect go your server before outside the method call

Comment: Try adding console.log inside the function to make sure its working

Comment: That's one big issue- our html button isn't triggering the call at all so it isn;t happening unfortunately. I think it's something in the button.

Comment: Ah! great catch. However, now I get an issue of being redirected to: http://ourwebsite/deleteMe?_method=delete

Comment: which, really we should want to be redirected to our original page but just have that object removed- not a new page.

Comment: Because you are using a form that should happen, you have to redirect to the desired page after that use `res.redirect('/your/page')`. Other wise you have to user jquery form submit, or some javascript ajax request to do that

Comment: Interesting. I will try to approach from the ajax call method, then.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra quote in the html at

action=**'**'deleteMe'